# Turning off HP Folio 9470 touchpad

Tags: touchpad, hp

I am trying to find out if there is a hot key to turn off the touchpad when using an external mouse.  In windows I just double tap in the upper left hand corner and it disables the touchpad.  Makes it nice when typing a long document or using an external mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Touchpad Indicator](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator) to assign a hotkey to enable and disable touchpad.

You can install Touchpad Indicator by downloading this [installation package](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator/0.7/0.7.6.2/+download/touchpad-indicator_0.7.6.2.orig.tar.gz). If there is some dependency issue, you can install `python-pyudev` as

```
  sudo apt-get install python-pyudev
```

Or,

You can install it via ppa as follows.

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```